# Change ImageButton background color on press

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I have seen many examples for ImageButton on hover, but they change the image. I just want to change the background color.

This is my selector -

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#4B88F7"/>
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#121212"/>
```

And my ImageButton -

```
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@color/actionbar_btn"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_remove" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a file `custom_selector.xml` in `res/drawable/` directory with the following content:

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/btn_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/btn_released"/>
</selector>
```

Then to apply this background to `ImageButton` by setting it as the `background`:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_selector.xml"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_remove" />
```

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Comment: it gave a exception. tag requires a drawable attribute or child tag defining a drawable

Comment: @reza, I edited my post. You'll have to create colors `btn_pressed` and `btn_released`.